# Regular expression for any characters bi-grams

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a text composed by any kind of symbols, like:

`string = 1234abdchdj星期上午十时*&()`

I want to find the character bi-grams with regular expression, to get an output like:

`12, 23, 34, ab, bd, ...`

I am actually using the following, with `python` and `regex`:

`bigrams = re.findall('(?=(\S\S))', string)`

but this gives me the **wrong output** since it misses characters and gives me actually half of the bi-grams I need:

`12, 34, ab, dc, ...`

Hope I've been clear enough, thank you in advance

Comment: This would be easier to do with a for loop, any reason why you need an re?

Comment: Yes that's true I was actually looping and was working fine. Than I started to use regular expression and I found that is the cleanest thing I can do.

Comment: This is going to be hard because you are using regular expression for something is wasn't intended to do if this is even possible

Comment: That's ok, at the end it was more curiosity than other. I spend a lot to find the right regex and I could not come up with a solution. That's why I wanted to make a question.

Comment: If you really want to use an re I guess you could use yours above and only print results at even indices

Comment: So you are not looking for https://ideone.com/j256zR ? What is missing in those matches?

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks, I have not idea why on my system was giving me that output. Maybe there was something related with other part of the code and I did not realize it.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip), it's probably the most pythonic way to do this.

```py
string = "1234abdchdj星期上午十时*&()"

for a, b in zip(string, string[1:]):
  print(a, b)
```

Depending on what you want to do for the last character `)`, you can also use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

for a, b in zip_longest(string, string[1:], fillvalue="-"):
  print(a, b)
```

Will print the same as before adding a line containing `) -` at the end.

In case you need to save a bit of memory you can even use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
from itertools import islice
string = "1234abdchdj星期上午十时*&()"

for a, b in zip(string, islice(string, 1, None)):
  print(a, b)
```

The classic slice `[1:]` creates a second array, while this creates an iterator over the same array. But unless you really need to save this memory I would stick to `string[1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try instead:

```
s = 'abcdef'
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    print(s[i:i+2])
```

or even better:

```
s = 'abcdef'
a = ''
for b in s:
    if a:
        print(a+b)
    a = b
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be hard if not impossible because you are trying to use a regular expression to solve a problem it isn't intended to solve. You can do this pretty cleanly in one line of python.

`ans = [x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x)-1, 2)]`